# opencv python- not able to write videos

Tags: python, opencv, video, video-capture, codec

I tried as given in the to tutorial, but I am not able to open the video. I guess there is some problem with the fourcc thing in OpenCV-Python. My code was as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
#fourCc = cv.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
fourCc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('X','V','I','D')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourCc,20.0,(640,480))

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret==True:
        frame = cv2.flip(frame,0)
        out.write(frame)
        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break

cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

It does create a file named output.avi (of non-zero size), but I am not able to play it, even using VLC.
NOTE: The same thing in C++ is working fine

Comment: can you try with: `fourCc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC('m', 'p', '4', 'v')` ? Another question is, how big is the size of your file? There might be only some header metadata in it.

Comment: I tried it, but it gives an error:- AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'cv'

Comment: And the size of output.avi is around 5 kB